# My script is not working to make zip file.

Tags: php

$files is an array to store file names.
createZipFile function is to make zip file. addFiles function returns true as Boolean value.

I am not sure where I am going wrong with the code.

```
<?php



$files[] = 'test.php';
$files[] = 'test1.php';
$files[] = 'test2.php';

createZipFile ( 'backup.zip', $files);

function createZipFile($pathtosave, $filestozip) {

    // create zip file
    $zip = new ZipArchive ();
    if ($zip->open ( $pathtosave, ZipArchive::CREATE ) != true)
    {
        throw new Exception( 'Cannot create or open the zip file' );
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ( $filestozip as $zipfiles )
        {
            $zip->addFile($zipfiles);           
        }       
    }


    // save it  
    $zip->close();
}

?>
```

Comment: Errors often don't show up until `$zip->close()`. This is particularly true of errors caused by file system permissions. Check the return value of `$zip->close()` and make sure your script has write permissions to the target file.

Comment: Hi $zip->close() returns false. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The code works correctly from the command line.  This is possibly a permission issue.  If you are executing this through a web server, make sure the user account that the web server runs under has write permissions to the directory in which you wish to create the zip file.  In this case it's the same directory as the script.  You can also set global write permissions with:

```
chmod 777 {web directory}
```

But this is a security risk.  It will allow any user account on the system to modify, create or delete files in the directory.

Comment: never do a chmod 777 instead make a chmod 775

Comment: I mentioned it was a security risk.  chmod 775 will not solve the problem unless the user account the web server is running under is a member of the group set for the directory.

Comment: Yes sure, but 775 don't give any write permission to other than user/group

Comment: Correct, but it also probably won't work unless he also sets the group ownership on the directory.  He would need root access for that.  chmod 775 is not a complete answer.  My original answer is the correct one.  The chmod 777 is designated 'You can also...'  with a security risk caveat.